# How to keep the first/last group in a group

Tags: python, pandas

How to keep the last group within a group using Pandas?

For example, given the following dataset:

```
    id     product   date
0   220    6647     2014-09-01 
1   220    6647     2014-09-03 
2   220    6647     2014-10-16
3   826    6647     2014-11-11
4   826    6647     2014-12-09
5   826    6647     2015-05-19
6   901    4555     2014-09-01
7   901    4555     2014-10-05
8   901    4555     2014-11-01
9   401    4555     2015-01-05
10  401    4555     2015-02-01
```

how to get the last id group from each of the product group succinctly?

```
    id     product   date
3   826    6647     2014-11-11
4   826    6647     2014-12-09
5   826    6647     2015-05-19
9   401    4555     2015-01-05
10  401    4555     2015-02-01
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50286010/get-first-and-last-elements-with-pd-grouper

Comment: so you want to group by product, extract the last id of each group, and then query those ids? start by doing `df.groupby('product')['id'].last()`

Comment: I think you want `df[df['id'].eq(df.groupby('product')['id'].transform('last'))]` or same without eq: `df[df['id'] == df.groupby('product')['id'].transform('last')]`

Comment: @Yuca: yes, that's exactly what I want. I tried your method but it turns out I need to use transform('last') instead of last() as suggested by Erfan. Thank you both!